# What's the meaning of the name P/poly?

Tags: terminology, complexity-classes

I understand the normal definitions of the P/poly class, but I'm curious how the name came about.

The syntax of the name looks like a quotient group, but I can't think of any way to define P/poly that would use a quotient. Is 'A/B' defined to be something like "the class of problems that would be solvable as efficiently as those in A when given B amounts of advice"?

If the 'poly' in 'P/poly' refers to the polynomial amount of advice, why is it not 'P/P'? That is, why do we have two different abbreviations for 'polynomial'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your second intuition is correct, the $poly$ refers to the bound on the advice. The first definition of this class (that I can find) is in Karp & Lipton's ["Turing Machines that Take Advice"](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CD0QFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fretro.seals.ch%2Fcntmng%3Bjsessionid%3D5A9720FEAA7983CCAA54B32278C778F0%3Fpid%3Densmat-001%3A1982%3A28%3A%3A71&ei=0MTBVMSbCoa58gXemILwDw&usg=AFQjCNEhwKQysMQ1vb-B4WIwIWaw_vJDuA&sig2=Y-WqZ_-kXXWiuCOCBbIjAQ&cad=rja) (pdf), and in particular:

> We are mainly interested in $poly$, the collection of all polynomially-bounded functions... (p. 192)

Of course they don't give the *reasons* for choosing that name, so on the speculative part!

Firstly, it should be clear that $P$ and $poly$, although both derived most immediately from the word *polynomial*, have rather distinct meanings. $P$ as a name refers to *deterministic polynomial time*, and as a class is the set of all problems solvable in such. $poly$ however is a bound on the advice function, not a time-complexity statement.

This is where I speculate that the difference in names stems from; $P$ and $poly$ are quite separate concepts and it would only serve to confuse if we were to write $P/P$ - this notation would suggest some idea of $\bigcup_{k} DTIME[n^{k}]/\bigcup_{k} DTIME[n^{k}]$, which is certainly an incorrect impression to gives, whereas $P/poly$ immediately suggest $P$ which has something polynomial attached to it *but is different to $P$*.